ものでもなく　in this sentence?

告げた後、香はわずかに首を傾げて考え込んだ。再び雰囲気が変わる。
抑え込んだものでもなく、柔和な私人のそれでもなく、仕事の先輩としてのそれだ。

"After I confess Kaori tilts her head a bit and goes into thinking. The mood changes again"
Then the narrator adds... "Shes' acting as a senpai" but what does 抑え込んだものでもなく、柔和な私人のそれでもなく mean here?
"Not shutting down, not as a private individual?"

Why the downvote? ...

These もの and それ are used as pronouns for 雰囲気. So you can read the sentence like:

抑え込んだ雰囲気でもなく、柔和な私人の雰囲気でもなく、仕事の先輩としての雰囲気だ。
It was neither a suppressed atmosphere nor the gentle atmosphere of a private individual, but rather that of a senpai at work.

